# Is $(t) = (e^{2t},ln|t|,\frac{1}{t})$ a flow line for the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(2x,z,-z^{2})$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Show that $\alpha(t) = (e^{2t},ln|t|,\frac{1}{t})$ ($t\neq 0$) is a flow line the vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=(2x,z,-z^{2})$.

I know that a flow line of a vector field are set the set of paths followed by a particle whose velocity is the given vector field... but what process I need to follow to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that $\alpha'(t) = F(\alpha(t))$. But $$F(\alpha(t)) = \left(2e^{2t}, \frac{1}{t}, \frac{-1}{t^2}\right).$$And what is $\alpha'(t)$?

Comment: $\alpha(t) = (e^{2t},ln|t|,\frac{1}{t})$ is a flow line for $F(x,y,z)$.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.